# How to Run Keycloak as a Gitlab CI Service

Tags: postgresql, docker, automated-tests, gitlab-ci, keycloak

### Description

I'm building an application that uses Keycloak to manage users. I want to set up a test job in Gitlab CI to run my regression tests on each commit. My test scripts require two services in order to run: postgres and keycloak. I'm able to connect successfully to the postrgres db, and all tests that don't require keycloak execute successfully; but, the ones requiring keycloak fail.

### Set up

Here is the test job part of my `.gitlab-ci` file:

```
test:
  image: node:12-alpine
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: postgres
    - name: postgres
      alias: keycloak-postgres
    - name: jboss/keycloak:9.0.2
      alias: keycloak
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: test-ci
    POSTGRES_DB: admin-db
    POSTGRES_USER: db-admin
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db-admin-password
    KEYCLOAK_USER: kc-admin
    KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: kc-admin-password
    DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
    DB_ADDR: keycloak-postgres
    DB_DATABASE: admin-db
    DB_USER: db-admin
    DB_SCHEMA: public
    DB_PASSWORD: db-admin-password
  except:
    refs:
      - tags
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[ci-release\]/
  script:
    - yarn test
```

I'm aware there might also be an issue with how I'm using two postgres instances here. I was having trouble getting one postgres instance to start with two databases, so I just added a new service (the two postgres services share the same environmental variables).

### Error Message

The error I get in the failed CI job is:

[image]

This error makes me think that the keycloak service is starting up, but that the default admin user is not being correctly initialized. This could be because starting the service with a simple `dokcer run` will not make this default user. There are some arguments that need to be passed. However, when starting this service via `docker-compose`, no arguments need to be passed only the setting of the `KEYCLOAK_USER` and `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD` variables is enough to initialize the user. I'm not sure how this differs in Gitlab CI.

Previously, before I added the second database service I was just getting an `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080` (my API code points to `https://keycloak:8080` since gitlab ci service's host is supposed to be the service name I believe; I'm not sure if this is the correct way to access the keycloak instance). Which again, makes me think that now, with 2 database instances, the service does actually start properly.

Any insight or help you can provide would be greatly appreciated and I'll make sure to respond in a timely manner to any questions or comments. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using two postgres database containers here instead of a single one?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I was having trouble getting the single postgres container to start with two databases (1 for the application and 1 for keycloak). I haven't seen a good fix for this other than downloading a file to change the entrypoint

Comment: Every make any progress on this?  I'm running into the same problem using a Keycloak image based on Keycloak 12.0.4. In my case I'm getting a 401 when I try to authenticate as the admin user which also leads me to believe that the admin user is not being set up correctly for some reason.